# When running $interval returns previous data after ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

My code is getting data from an API that is constanstly getting data from a DB. I have a button with ng-submit that sends the serial number and uses a GET verb to obtain the data. However i want to keep updating the data that is displayed. Therefore i'm using an interval and using the same function when retrieving the first time. When running the $interval it's also returning previous serial number data.

**HTML**

```
     <form ng-submit="main.loadData()">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon stncolor" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Servicetag" maxlength="7" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" ng-model="main.servicetag">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Load</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
(function(){
  angular.module('mainApp', [])
  .controller('mainController', mainController);

  mainController.$inject = ['$http', '$interval']
  function mainController($http, $interval){
    var self = this;

  self.loadData = function(){;
    getServiceTagData(self.servicetag);
    refresh(self.servicetag);
  };

  // Get initial Data
  var getServiceTagData = function(stn){
    $http.get("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/NPIAPI/api/GetAlltestData/" + stn)
     .then(function(response){
       self.localizationdata = response.data;
    }, function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  };

  // Refresh Data from localization
  var refresh = function(stn){
    $interval(function(){
      getServiceTagData(stn);
      console.log("Refreshed Localization Data");
   },30000);
 };
}
})();
```

[When checking one serial number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEwGS.png)

[When checking another serial number, previous returned array is present as well as new array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S38HX.png)

Comment: Have you confirmed by inspecting network traffic that the data being returned by the API is updating?

Comment: Yes, it's being updated. however this part self.localizationdata is loading previous and new data.